# Can't Open URLs in Lync 2010

Tags: windows-vista, url, hyperlink, office-communicator-2007, lync-2010

On my workstation computer running Windows Vista, I am unable to open URLs in both Lync 2010 and Communicator 2007 R2 by clicking on them. The problem started with Communicator 2007 R2, and we since have upgraded to Lync 2010, but the problem persists. The problem occurred seemingly by random one day, and my coworkers are still able to click links. I have full admin access on the machine, any ideas?

Comment: If you try from a different local account does the problem still persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem with outlook before. Resetting the default browser to IE worked for me. If you have another browser installed set it as default, then do the same for IE.

You can force IE to check it is default using this regkey if required

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"Check_Associations"="yes"
```

Good luck

Comment: I don't work today so I can't try this solution, but I'm going to award the bounty as I found it to be the most useful answer, rather than letting the 50 points go to waste. I think this might solve the issue though, as I do not have IE as my default browser and I never thought to try this.

Comment: Turns out that did work, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the User Accounts Control is off and that your Antivirus is not blocking your Lync software.

Comment: Disabling both UAC and my antivirus software did not help.

Comment: Is there any specific error message once you try to click the URLs?

Comment: Nothing at all - simply nothing happens when they are clicked.